# Why does the Android 6.0+ OS Ask the user to manage and control phone calls if you specify ReadPhoneState?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I use the device id and sim number from the device to generate a UUID that will be associated with a login account.

Since Android 6 or API-23 and up, we are now required to ask the user if this is ok.

My problem is that when it asks the user for permission it says the app is trying to manage and make phone calls, which is not the case.

Since no user in their right mind would allow controlling their calls if you ask only to collect information, is there a way to customize this message to be closer to the truth ?

I honestly think that android should make these permissions and requests closer to the truth, It sets the developer in a bad light. No amount of explaining before you ask permission can justify why some permissions are needed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32943859/1527458

Comment: Thanks for the help, seems to be working

Comment: Bu still, it is unfair to show **"Manage and control phone calls"** if I am only trying to read the phone's IMEI.

Comment: yes, android surely need to sort out these messages, as it does not relate to anything close to what you are trying to do. Giving the user a total misunderstanding. Users don't care what you tell them in the pre-message, once they see the android permission message they flip.