# How do I add a notification before my Unity app asks the user for permissions?

Tags: unity-game-engine

My game currently asks users for permissions on start up before I am given a chance to explain to users why I need those permissions. 
[This is what my users currently see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PXkK.jpg)

This is an example of what I want to show my users before the permission is asked.
[This example is from Injustice 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89R5I.jpg)

Please advise.

Comment: Show us some code for what you tried so far and someone will be more likely to help you out!

Comment: Seems u need to go native https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942909/provide-custom-text-for-android-m-permission-dialog