# How to change the alert message when we download some files in react native app and provide permission access to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: react-native

In my react native app iam downloading some file so before downloading iam giving permission access  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ,

whenever iam downloading some file i will be getting alert  message saying "Allow name to access photos,media and files on your device"

how we can edit this message

Answer (score 0):

You cannot customized the message, please check the reason in here:

[Provide custom text for Android M permission dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942909/provide-custom-text-for-android-m-permission-dialog)